# I have a friction sound coming from the front bottom leftish side of my car - what should I look at? (Video inside)

Tags: noise, nissan, car, sentra

[Nissan Sentra 2001 here]

I have a friction sound of metal rubbing together that is coming from the front of my car. It is not the brakes because it happens any time I cold start the car, not particularly when I am braking.

Here's a Video of the Issue where you can hear the sound:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFj3kBrDK9c

It's coming from the front left side of the car.

I have noticed it happens the worst when I COLD start the car. If I drive it for a while, come to a stop and then try to start within a few minutes again - the sound is very minimal (but has been increasing for the last few days). Definitely worse when I COLD start.

I really dont know what to start looking at - so any pointers could help here.

Comment: Welcome to the site. That's a nasty noise. Does the noise occur only when the vehicle is moving? What about during braking?

Comment: Yes, please don't drive your vehicle anymore until you figure this out. That sounds like you've got some major damage happening (or has happened). Very nasty.

Comment: Agree - shouldn't be driving that. My money is on a completely collapsed bearing, or (I've only ever seen this once) the top bolt has fallen out of the caliper and the caliper is grinding on the inside of the wheel.

Comment: @Zaid Yes, only when i am moving. Gets a little better at higher speeds but bad at low speeds